# How to filter empty values from a column of Python Polars Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a python polars dataframe as-

```
df_pol = pl.DataFrame({'test_names':[['Mallesham','','Bhavik','Jagarini','Jose','Fernando'],
                                    ['','','','ABC','','XYZ']]})
```

I would like to get a count of elements from each list in test_names field not considering the empty values.

```
df_pol.with_column(pl.col('test_names').arr.lengths().alias('tot_names'))
```

[image]

Here it is considering empty strings into count, this is why we can see 6 names in list-2. actually it has only two names.

required output as:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `arr.eval` to run any polars expression on the list's elements. In an `arr.eval` expression, you can `pl.element()` to refer to the lists element and then apply an expression.

Next we simply use a `filter` expression to prune the values we don't need.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "test_names":[
        ["Mallesham","","Bhavik","Jagarini","Jose","Fernando"],
        ["","","","ABC","","XYZ"]
    ]
})

df.with_column(
    pl.col("test_names").arr.eval(pl.element().filter(pl.element() != ""))
)
```

```
shape: (2, 1)
┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ test_names                          │
│ ---                                 │
│ list[str]                           │
╞═════════════════════════════════════╡
│ ["Mallesham", "Bhavik", ... "Fer... │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ["ABC", "XYZ"]                      │
└─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question - basically we want to apply a filter within each list element.

We do this by using `arr.eval` which allows us to do operations inside the `Series` on each row and use `pl.element` to be a proxy for the `Series` on each row.

```py
(
    df_pol
    .with_column(
        pl.col('test_names').arr.eval(
            pl.element().filter(pl.element().str.lengths()>0)
         )
         .arr.lengths()
         .alias('tot_names')
     )
)
```